# Kubernetes external secret with hashicorp vault - Error handling if secret not available

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, argocd

In our helm based Kubernetes project, we're fetching external secrets from hashicorp vault, as shown in the below example. Deployment is done using Argocd

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: hello-vault-service
spec:
  backendType: vault
  vaultMountPoint: my-kubernetes-vault-mount-point
  vaultRole: my-vault-role
  data:
  - name: password
    key: secret/data/hello-service/credentials
```

If vault path `secret/data/hello-service/credentials` is missing, currently we are getting 404 error. We need to handle this error by taking the default dummy secret value from values.yaml if external secret path not found.

Could someone please help

Comment: You should open an issue to the external-secret repo, [issue](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets/issues?). I guess it doesn't support such features yet.

Comment: Thanks @KamolHasan Have raised a ticket to ES team